# Change input scope in Textbox while it's used

Tags: xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I have started learning WP 8.1 recently and run into an issue. I'm trying to "reimplement" some functions I found across applications. One of apps is able to change the InputScope after 6 letters have been written. You put your logon there which is built of 6 letters and 4 digits. The applications text box automagically changes scope after 6 letters have been input, changing the scope to numbers only.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="113,164,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="TextBox"
             InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Length.ToString(); //Display length on string on textChanged, not important right now
    if (TextBox1.Text.Length < 4) {
        InputScope inputScope = new InputScope();
        InputScopeName inputScopeName = new InputScopeName();
        inputScopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.NumberFullWidth;
        inputScope.Names.Add(inputScopeName);
        TextBox1.InputScope = inputScope;
    }
}
```

Please remember I'm beginner and could have made some awful and easy mistakes. I hope I can learn from you a bit :)

Comment: Seems like inputscope is being somehow fixed once TextBox shows the keyboard for the first time.

Comment: Would be beneficial if we somehow figured how it works. https://www.windowsphone.com/pl-pl/store/app/ingmobile/40dc04a4-6287-4bfb-8ddd-d86026da3034 here is the link to related app I'm trying to mimick, if that helps.